# Como pegar e contar imagens com php?

Tags: php, html, contador

como consigo contar e pegar, em php, a imagem de cada um desses elementos do código abaixo?
NÃO POSSO usar um input file 'multiple', pois não serão apenas essas linhas, como abaixo, será algo dinâmico, e que poderá conter outros elementos (textarea por exemplo) no meio dessas linhas

```
                <input class="tf" type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*">
                <input class="tf" type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*">
                <input class="tf" type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*">
                <input class="tf" type="file" name="pic[]" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30821/discussion-on-question-by-alexandre-martins-montebelo-como-pegar-e-contar-imagen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itere o array recebido da variável global `$_FILES`

```
// Obtém o tamanho do array, ou seja, a quantidade de imagens recebidas
$count = count($_FILES['pic']['tmp_name']);

// Faz a iteração
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['pic']['name'][$i]; // nome do arquivo
    $file_type = $_FILES['pic']['type'][$i]; // tipo
    $file_error = $_FILES['pic']['error'][$i]; // código de erro do upload, se houver
    $file_size = $_FILES['pic']['size'][$i]; // tamanho em bytes
    $file_path = $_FILES['pic']['tmp_name'][$i]; // caminho completo do path temporário.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O PHP agrupa arquivos enviados com o mesmo nome de uma maneira pouco intuitiva, eu criei uma função (https://gist.github.com/pedrosancao/9100827) que interpreta os valores recebidos de forma que permite o tratamento conforme sugerido na documentação [Upload de arquivos com o método POST](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.file-upload.post-method.php) seja o mesmo, independente se você receber um ou mais arquivos.

Ao chamar `parse_files()` é adicionado um sufixo numérico ao nome do campo do formulário, de forma que os dados fiquem da seguinte maneira:

```
// estrutura original 
echo $_FILES['pic']['name'][0]; // exemplo1.jpg
echo $_FILES['pic']['name'][1]; // exemplo2.jpg
// estrutura depois do tratamento
$files = parse_files();
echo $files['pic_0']['name']; // exemplo1.jpg
echo $files['pic_1']['name']; // exemplo2.jpg
```

Além disso como foi relatado o erro *Undefined index: pic* o seu formulário não deve conter o atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, o que deve estar causando parte do problema.

---

Definição da função, caso o link acima esteja inacessível.

```
<?php
/**
 * Parses the PHP's $_FILES array when multiple file input is used, it will
 * return an array as each file was from a different input. It also works
 * when multiple and single inputs are mixed
 * 
 * @author   Pedro Sanção
 * @license  MIT Licence
 */
function parse_files() {
    $files = array();
    foreach ($_FILES as $fieldName => $file) {
        reset($file);
        $key = key($file);
        if (is_array($file[$key])) {
            $propeties = array_keys($file);
            $fieldNamekeys = array_keys($file[$key]);
            foreach ($fieldNamekeys as $namekey) {
                $fileKey = "{$fieldName}_{$namekey}";
                $files[$fileKey] = array();
                foreach ($propeties as $property) {
                    $files[$fileKey][$property] = $file[$property][$namekey];
                }
            }
        } else {
            $files[$fieldName] = $file;
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```